# <asp:RegularExpressionValidator and RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace

Tags: asp.net, regex

Is there an easy way of using the `RegularExpressionValidator` control while ignoring white space?

I can use a custom validator control with `Regex` and `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, but it would be good to just have an option in the `RegularExpressionValidator` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your regex with

> (?x:   )

so "a b c" becomes "(?x:a b c)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the regular expression validator want to validate with javascript, too, so you want to make sure your expression will work with both the .Net and javascript regex engines.  That means that using .IgnorePatterWhitespace isn't the best idea.

Comment: But, you can set EnableClientScript to false and then it's not an issue.